# Where can I find books for Azra to equip?

Tags: defenders-quest

During my play-through of Defender's Quest, I have noticed when equipping weapons and armour for my companions that it is possible to equip books for Azra to use, but I have yet to find any of these mysterious artefacts.

[image]

I think that I am close to completing the main campaign and haven't found any books yet, and was wondering if I had missed any along the way.

Where can I find books?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My name's Lars Doucet, I'm the lead developer for Defender's Quest!

Technically, the game is in public beta for now, so the early release you're playing only has one "magic book" for Azra to equip. We're going to support a good bit more in the final version of the game.

You can definitely access the existing books through save-game hacking, which is the only way to access books other than "furious end" - but beware, anything in the old version of the game might be glitchy or horribly unbalanced. :)

Books will be a big feature in the upcoming expansion to the game, which all of you will receive as a free update. The other big feature is more bonus missions and a New Game+ mode, which raises the level cap and gives you new challenges to play with.

Here's a full list of the ones we're planning (most are already functional in our latest test build):

> Chain Lightning - lightning chains to additional targets
>  Shock Lightning - lightning stuns enemies
>  Furious Start - newly summoned defenders start frenzied
>  Furious End - defenders below X HP have frenzy
>  Slow Start - Newly spawned enemies are slowed
>  Slow End - Enemies approaching the exit are slowed
>  Psi Shield - enemies deal PSI damage instead of HP to Azra for the first few hits
>  Crystal Patch - start with several crystals near the spawn area
>  Explosive Start - on boost/summon defenders release a small explosion
>  Explosive End - on defeat defenders release a large explosion
>  Light of Glory - applies LIGHT to enemies when casting heal
>  Light of Judgment - applies BLIND to enemies when casting heal

We're still balancing them - some of the more powerful variants will have a small increase to cooldown or casting cost of the associated spell.

Answer (score 4):

I got 'Furious End' from the bonus quest 'Endless 1'- only available after completing the main quest.
 It gives defenders with health below 25% the Frenzy skill. At the end of the quest it says something about not having any characters to equip the book on, but alas I was able to equip it on the main toon.

Answer (score 3):

As S.Skov said "Furious End" seems to be the only book you can legitimately get. However if you are not above a bit of light hacking there are a few more books to be had.

> 16 books in total, some are non functional. To obtain, first export your game, it should show up as defenders_quest_save_slot_1.dfq, **make a copy of this file or you can mess up your saved game**. Open this file with your text editor (TextEdit for Mac, I think it's textpad for pc) scroll to the bottom and you'll see the character's inventory. You're looking for; (item _class="weapon" type="book"), if you already have "Furious End" it will show as; (level="4"), the levels available are 1-16 from what I've found. After you're done just import the hacked save file in an empty slot on the start screen.

Suppose you could do a lot more with this, but that would be cheating ;-) I did play the game all the way to just shy of the last three Extreme's, but after finishing was also curious about there only being one book.

Answer (score 1):

As Oertos said, you can inventory edit more books into place by modifying the save file (which is easy to do and has a nice message from the game designer embedded into it ^^)

Using the following code, you can get all of the books at the same time.

<item _class="weapon" type="book" level="1" owner="" alt="0"/> <item _class="weapon" type="book" level="2" owner="" alt="0"/> <item _class="weapon" type="book" level="3" owner="" alt="0"/> etcetera...

By adding that code in before the </inventory> tag, you'll have a full copy of every book to peruse at your leisure. I haven't checked them all out yet, here are the few I've found:

> 1 - Chain Lightning = Lightning strikes 1 additional target with diminishing power for each skill point in Lightning. 2 - Fire Storm = Lightning catches enemies on fire. 3 - Furious Start = Newly summoned defenders have frenzy. 4 - Furious End = Defenders below 25% health gain frenzy. 5 - Regeneration = (NOT FUNCTIONAL) Casting Heal doubles all defender's regeneration - lasting 1 second per skill point in Heal. 6 - Persist = (NOT FUNCTIONAL) Defenders persist as invincible ghosts after death for 2 seconds per skill point in Heal. 7 - Slow End = (NOT FUNCTIONAL) Enemies within slow down as they approach $MCG. 8 - Slow Start = (NOT FUNCTIONAL) Newly spawned enemies are slowed temporarily. 9 - Psi Shield = Enemies that hit $MCG deduct Psi instead of HP. Psi Shield sustains 1 hit per skill point in Crystal.

Hopefully this helps!